# Why APT::Periodic variables are set in two files?

Tags: 16.04, apt

...namely in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic and /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.

```
$ dpkg-query -S /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic
update-notifier-common: /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic

$ dpkg-query -S /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
```

Comment: 20auto-upgrades is generated by dpkg-reconfigure for Unattended Upgrades instead of installed directly. Source: https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unattended-upgrades-developers/unattended-upgrades/trunk/view/head:/README.md. Since each of the two files comes from a different package, using separate files makes installation and removal simpler.

Comment: @user535733 There is no reference to file 20auto-upgrades in your linked text.

Comment: See lines 84-93. While it's not explicit, that is how the file is created. Feel free to try it. Feel free also to offer a patch to the documentation.

Comment: @user535733 the documentation is old; https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/master/README.md seems to be more up-to-date, but I am not sure, if it is the official one. `dpkg-reconfigure` may modify 20auto-upgrades, but if I delete the file, it will not change the configuration.